# Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump back and forth to SublimeSBT console and the editor in sublime?

Tags: scala, keyboard-shortcuts, sbt, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

This is in regards to SublimeSBT plugin. I need an easy way to switch back and forth between the SBT console (not sublime console which is CTRL+`) and the main editor without having to use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

There are some shortcuts [defined in the plugin](https://github.com/jarhart/SublimeSBT/blob/master/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap#L2), you can switch to the console with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Then you can switch to the source with <kbd>ESC</kbd>. It will close the console panel, but if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> again it will appear with the same state as before.